# Custom Errors Work Locally Not Once Deployed On IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, http-status-codes

I have the following:

`Web.config`

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/ShowError">
  <error redirect="~/Error/ShowError/400" statusCode="400" />
  <error redirect="~/Error/ShowError/401" statusCode="401" />
  <error redirect="~/Error/ShowError/403" statusCode="403" />
  <error redirect="~/Error/ShowError/404" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
</system.web>
```

`ErrorController`

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult ShowError(int id)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = id;
        switch (id)
        {
            case 400:
                return View("~/Views/Error/400.cshtml");
            case 401:
                return View("~/Views/Error/401.cshtml");
            case 403:
                return View("~/Views/Error/403.cshtml");
            case 404:
                return View("~/Views/Error/404.cshtml");
            default:
                return View("~/Views/Error/404.cshtml");
        }
    }
}
```

`FilterConfig`

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
```

Locally everything works fine, I get a custom error page and am happy, however as soon as I deploy the site to my web server, I no longer get my custom error messages and only the generic:

[image]

Do I need to add anything specific for the IIS configuration in my online environment?

I've compared the local `Web.config` with the deployed `Web.config` and there isn't anything different (that I can see).

Comment: did you enable extension less: https://svenaelterman.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/using-asp-net-4-0-extension-less-routing-on-iis-7-5/ ?

Comment: try installing: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/980368

Comment: Thanks for the response Khanh, I've been asured that the update has been installed. Never the less I tried `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` with no luck.

Comment: try  `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true`

Comment: That did the trick =) thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is overwritten by IIS custom error.

Try:

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true
```